# Sudomain automatically redirect to https

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I'm having HTTPS with my main domain ie https://example.com.
And I want to use subdomain without HTTPS ie, http://hello.example.com but the problem is it automatically redirects to HTTPS. How do I avoid that?

This is my current **.htaccess** structure:

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 


# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this with a Middleware.
For example:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class HttpsProtocol {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
            if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'prod' AND [your chek url without subdomain]) {
                return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri()); //with https
            }

            return $next($request); 
    }
}
```

Change `[your chek url without subdomain]`

And adding setting the rule at Kernel.php:

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...........

    // append HTTPS middleware 
    'App\Http\Middleware\HttpsProtocol'       

];
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Alternatively, You can add this code : (*I think It's better one*)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
```

Replace `example` with your domain name and Add this code after `line 9`

<s>`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.example\.com`</s>

Comment: I tried but nothing happened means subdomain automatically redirects to https

Comment: Can you post final version of your `.htaccess` after adding my code?

Comment: Strange.. Did you check my previous code? I mean the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.example\.com` one?

Comment: Umm, both are being used on my server and works, I'm puzzled now.

Comment: Are You sure the redirection is not happening outside of `.htaccess`? I mean any php script or other?